# Differences between using one executable with threads or many executables

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, cpu-architecture

Reading about how does the OS handle the executables, I couldn't figure out if is better to use one executable with many threads inside or use many independent executables. The same task is performed, but I need to process many requests. Is there an executable limits to run simultaneous threds? Does it matter or every OS task goes to same CPU queue and doesnt matter the source executable?

Which is better? One with many threads or many executables? If could give an explanation or share some doc I would be greateful.

Comment: `which is better` - **for what**? without knowing your specific use case **in detail**, this is unanswerable. and if you have enough details, i guess the answer becomes pretty obvious.  i recommend taking the [Tour], as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: One difference would be that thread share memory address space. Processes do not (you'll need shared memory if you need such sharing, which is less trivial). But as commented above we do not know what is your use case and whether this is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the OS scheduling them to CPUs, there's no difference; modern mainstream OSes (Windows / Linux / MacOS) use a 1:1 thread model so every user-space thread is a separately schedulable OS task, not "[green threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads)".

Solaris did or does have an N:M thread model, where user-space threads can be scheduled onto a "thread pool" of OS-level threads, with user-space context switching in some cases, but most other OSes don't.

So either way can take full advantage of all the CPU cores in the system; which is better depends on the use-case.  Threads of a single process share memory (and file descriptors) with each other, and are cheaper to create than new processes.  But still not that cheap; often you want to have a pool of worker threads that you wake up or queue work for, not start a new thread or process when a new request comes in.

Comment: Thank you Peter! This was a generic question just to understand exatacly what you explained.